# intel mkl library for fortran

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl

i am using Fortran to estimate the probability of sovereign risk; so i write my program and i call mkl_vsl in the following form:

```
:
:
include 'mkl_vsl.fi'
:
:
USE MKL_VSL_TYPE
USE MKL_VSL
:
:
```

Codeblocks GNU fortran compiler send me an error message :

```
||=== Build: Debug in thesis (compiler: GNU Fortran Compiler) ===|
C:\___\___\____\___\___\mod_nonlinear_solver.f90|6|Error: Can't open included file 'mkl_vsl.fi'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the directories where gfortran searches for include files: [gfortran-doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options). I guess the compilation step within Codeblocks doesn't set that setting

```sh
$ gfortran -I$(MKLROOT)/include
```

where the `MKLROOT` variable is something similar to

```sh
$ echo $MKLROOT 
/opt/exports/intel20/compilers_and_libraries_2020.1.217/linux/mkl
```